# Error Executing Trie Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, trie

i want to insert a string and make a search opeartion using trie data structure.This is my first implementation using pointers so i am really confused what i am doing wrong in the code,It is giving compilation error.please help to debug it and please tell me what is wrong in my pointer logic.

```
typedef struct trie {
    unordered_multimap<char, struct trie> child;
    bool isEnd;
} trie;
trie* newtrienode()
{
    trie* newnode = (trie*)malloc(sizeof(trie));
    newnode->isEnd = false;
    return newnode;
}
trie* root = newtrienode();
void insert(string word)
{
    trie* current = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char ch = word[i];
        trie* node = current->child[ch];
        if (node == NULL) {
            trie* node = newtrienode();
            current->child.insert(pair<char, trie>(ch, node));
        }
        current = node;
    }
    current->isEnd = true;
}
bool search(string word)
{
    trie* current = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char ch = word[i];
        trie* node = current->child[ch];
        if (node == NULL) {
            return false;
        }
        current = node;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what have been mentioned in comments, I see a few problems with the code.

1.

```
trie* newnode = (trie*)malloc(sizeof(trie));
```

This doesn't create an object of type `trie`, it only allocates a block of memory the size of `trie` and assigns the pointer to it to the variable `newnode`. In particular, it doesn't call the constructor of `unordered_multimap`. Any access to the `child` member via that pointer produces undefined behavior. Besides, you never free that memory.

2.

```
typedef struct trie {
    unordered_multimap<char, struct trie> child;
    bool isEnd;
} trie;
```

At the second line you are declaring a `unordered_multimap` data member with an incomplete type `trie` as the second template parameter. Some compilers allow that, but the standard doesn't require them to. `shared_ptr`, on the other hand, is required to be usable with an incomplete type as the template parameter. Also, a node can only have one subtree per character, so you don't need a multimap; a map will suffice. So I'd suggest using `unordered_map<char, shared_ptr<trie>>` and replacing all occurrences of `trie*` with `shared_ptr<trie>`. It will also take care of deleting the objects once `root` is released.

The `newtrienode()` function will look like this:

```
shared_ptr<trie> newtrienode()
{
    shared_ptr<trie> newnode (new trie());
    newnode->isEnd = false;
    return newnode;
}
```

3.

```
trie* node = current->child[ch];
if (node == NULL) {
```

`operator[]` doesn't return `NULL` when the key doesn't exist. It inserts a default-constructed object into the container and returns the reference to it. In order to check whether a key exist, use `find` or `count`.

4.

```
trie* node = current->child[ch];
if (node == NULL) {
    trie* node = newtrienode();
    current->child.insert(pair<char, trie>(ch, node));
}
current = node;
```

Note that in the third line you're declaring a new variable. The variable  `node` declared on the first line doesn't get changed.